# how to move div to left on mouseenter and move back with mouseleave or better solution?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have team block which I need to animate on "hover". 5 persons inline and when I hover on the first then display content about him over other persons and persons going to opacity 0, when mouse leave block about person disappear then person opacity is 1. The biggest problem is when hovering over other persons. Hover on the second person shows content about but move left to the same position where is person one and the same procedure opacity 0-1. This moving is for all persons except the first one.

one of many[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3va1s2mf/136/)
I was also try something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".person").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".person").not(this).stop(true, true).animate({ left: "-=0" }, "slow");
        $(".person").not($(this)).animate({"opacity":"0"}, "slow");
        $(".person").not($(this)).css("pointer-events","none");
    });
    $(".person").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".person").not(this).stop(true, true).animate({ left: "auto" }, "slow");
        $(".person").not($(this)).animate({"opacity":"1"}, "slow");
        $(".person").not($(this)).css("pointer-events","");
    });
});
```

the biggest problem is animate left, it goes left but without delay and won't go back on mouseleave and pointer events. when hovering it blinks